# Wrapping AvalonDock tab contents with AdornerDecorator

Tags: datatemplate, wpftoolkit, avalondock

Validation errors disappear when tabs are changed in AvalonDock. Therefore, I need to change tab content template in AvalonDock to wrap the content with AdornerDecorator. But I don't know how to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem, but do not delete the question since it can be useful for others. This is the solution:

```
<ad:DockingManager>
    <ad:DockingManager.LayoutItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <AdornerDecorator>
                <ContentControl Content="{Binding}"/>
            </AdornerDecorator>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ad:DockingManager.LayoutItemTemplate>
</ad:DockingManager>
```